# Discounted expectation of generic $\mathbb{C}^2$ function

Tags: brownian-motion, finance-mathematics, asset-pricing, geometric-brownian

Consider a standard geometric Brownian motion $V_t$ with drift $\mu<r$ and standard deviation $1$.

It holds that the discounted expectation is
$$E\left[\int_t^\infty e^{-r(s-t)} V_s ds | V_t \right] = \frac{V_t}{r-\mu}$$
provided that $r > \mu$ and diverges for $r < \mu$.

Does a similar result hold for any $\mathbb{C}^2$ function? That is consider a function that satisfies
$$R f(V) = c + \mu V f'(V) + V^2 f''(V)$$
What is the discounted expectation of it for possible values of $R-r$:
$$E\left[\int_t^\infty e^{-r(s-t)} f(V_s) ds | V_t \right] = ?$$

My current guess is that the solution is:

1. For $r > R$, the solution is $\frac{f(V_t)}{r-R} + const$.
2. For $r < R$, the expectation diverges.
3. Not sure for $r = R$.

To calculate 1, I have derived an ODE for the expectation and used $f$ coming from the solution of its ODE as a non-homogenous term. Then solved with variation of coefficients. But I am not sure how to prove point 2 and how to proceed with 3.

Comment: You can find the expectation of $f(V_s)$ thru Breeden-Litzenberger 1978 or Carr-Madan 2001. If $f$ is sufficiently "nice", you can find closed form expectations $E(f(V_s))$ as a function of $s$. The rest is integration, no?

Comment: I think this is correct thanks

Comment: I've modified the question to make it clearer, let me please know if you have thoughts on this thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The guessed solution is correct. Also the case $r=R$ diverges. To find the solution solve the ODE for the expectation of $f(V)$:

$$d\mathbb{E}(f) = R \mathbb{E}(f) - c$$
which is obtained from applying ito's lemma to $f$ and replacing the ODE for the drift term. The solution can be replaced into the expectation (DCT applies because $f$ is bounded).

The rest is integration.